# Syntactic function of "to kill him" in the sentence "I want you to kill him"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

1. Is the sentence "I want you to kill him" grammatically correct?
2. What is the syntactic function of "to kill him" in the above sentence?

Comment: _To kill him_ is the verb phrase of an infinitive complement clause _(for) you to kill him_, which is the direct object of the verb _want_.

Comment: Dear Mr. Lawler, thank you very much for your helpful answer.